# Why are these 'counter' examples in topology?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

In [*Counterexamples in Topology*](https://www.scribd.com/doc/142689570/Counterexamples-In-Topology-Steen-Seebach-pdf) from *Steen & Seebach* I found the following compact and Hausdorff counterexamples with some properties: 
 
- Lexicographically ordered square: 1st-countable, not separable, not 2nd-countable, not metrizable, connected, not path-connected. 
- Concentric circles: 1st-countable, completely normal, not separable, not 2nd-countable, not metrizable. 
- Helly Space: Separable, 1st-countable, not 2nd-countable, not metrizable, sequentially compact. 
- Double Arrow: Separable, 1st-countable, not 2nd-countable, homogeneous, not metrizable. 
 
I am trying to see exactly why these spaces behave differently from compact metric spaces, but because of a lack of intuition in the properties of compact metric spaces, I can not see why these topological examples are special. 
Could you please give me some theorems/properties which compact metric spaces do behave like, but these examples don't?

Comment: The listed spaces *are* compact. Hence there is no "theorem/properties which compact spaces do behave like, but these examples don't". However, a common intuition is that compact spaces are almost as good as finite sets. Then properties like not separable might by counter-intuitive ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for your comment. You forgot the word 'metric' in the quote though. I am searching for theorems/properties which metric compact spaces do behave like, but these topological compact spaces do not behave like. Being not separable is indeed a good example, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Metric spaces are 1st countable.
Compact metric spaces are 2nd countable.

Answer (score 3):

1. All metric spaces are $T_6.$ The lex-order-topology on $[0,1]^2$ is $T_5,$ as are all linear spaces, but this one is  not $T_6$: Singleton subsets are $G_{\delta}$ but the closed set $[0,1]\times \{0,1\}$ is not a $G_{\delta}$ set.
2. Separable metric spaces are 2nd-countable. Compact metric spaces are separable. The Helly Space and the Double-Arrow space are separable but not 2nd-countable.
3. I may have seen the Two Circles Space but by a different name.

Comment: The Two Circles example is just the Alexandroff/Aleksandrov double of the circle (inner circle points have usual neighbourhoods unioned with the punctured copy of that neighbourhood in the outer circle, outer circle points are all isolated). All three spaces come from the same Aleksandrov/Urysohn paper on compacta from the early  1900's, they're true classics.